How to troubleshoot strange cursor behavior in Office 365 apps?
Just recently, the typing cursor in Office 365 apps started behaving strangely. I am using Win10-64bit-19045.5131 and O365-2412-18314.2.
In Outlook, the typing cursor keeps jumping backwards, even though the typing appears in the expected location. In Word, the typing cursor jumps down slightly while typing, but as with Outlook, the typed text appears in the correct place.
This occurs with both the built-in laptop keyboard and two different external keyboards, one Bluetooth, one USB-C.
Example behavior:
Outlook

Word

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot?

I would try a different keyboard

This occurs with both the built-in laptop keyboard and two different external keyboards, one Bluetooth, one USB-C. I'll update the post to reflect that.

Try toggling hardware acceleration in the application options.

Looks like your case is more related to the cursor, please refer to this article to troubleshooting: Troubleshoot Strange Cursor Behavior in Office 365 Apps on Win 10.

Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.
